# WordPress MySQL query: copy data from a table to another

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'm using a wordpress plugin for a while to add a "Sources" custom field into the end of each post. The thing is this plugin isn't updated for 4 years and I want to get rid of it. But I can't afford to lose the saved sources for each post. I could manually edit these posts one by one, but after looking at the database with the query below I found that theres over 19k posts using this sources plugin.

```
SELECT *
FROM `wp_postmeta`
WHERE `meta_key` = 'sa_source'
AND `meta_value` <> ''
```

The sources are stored in `wp_postmeta` table, `meta_value` column. As I'm not great at SQL, I'm here looking for some help. I need to insert the content from:

- `wp_postmeta` table, `meta_value` column. Where `meta_value` is not empty

into the end of:

- `wp_posts` table, `post_content` column. Where the `post_id` from `wp_postmeta` is the same as `ID` from `wp_posts`

Answer (score 1):

The next query can resolve your problem:

```
    update
      wp_posts
    join 
      wp_postmeta on wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.post_id
    set
      -- add mata_value content to current post_content with one space
      post_content = concat(post_content, ' ', meta_value)
    where 
      wp_postmeta.meta_value is not null and wp_postmeta.meta_value <> '';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot my man! After some testing I made the changes in the production server, everything is working fine. This is the code I've used:

`UPDATE wp_posts
JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID
SET post_content = concat(post_content, '<p>&nbsp;</p> <strong>Source: </strong>', meta_value)
WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_value IS NOT NULL
AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'sa_source'
AND wp_postmeta.meta_value <> '';`